# Removing non-letter characters from data using SELECT DISTINCT in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, distinct

I have a table containing data of city name like "(Istanbul)" and "Istanbul"

I am trying to show only city name whether it is in original form or in parentheses.

For that I am using the following code.

```
<?php
require_once "config.php";
$sql = $conn->query( "SELECT DISTINCT city FROM countries ORDER BY city" );
if ( $sql->num_rows > 0 ) {
// output data of each row
while ( $row = $sql->fetch_assoc() ) {
    echo '<li> <input type="checkbox" name="cityName" value="' . $row[ "city" ] . '" />' . $row[ "city" ] . '</li>';
}
} else {
echo "0 results";
}
?>
```

I tried to use 
    replace(replace(city, '(', ''), ')', '')

But I cannot incorporate it into the SELECT DISTINCT.

I am not sure if it is even possible.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add alias for use the same result in order by too

```
     "SELECT DISTINCT replace(replace(city, '(', ''), ')', '')  as city 
      FROM countries 
      ORDER BY city"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query hope it's helpfull:-

```
$sql = $conn->query( "SELECT DISTINCT city FROM countries ORDER BY city WHERE city LIKE '(%)'" );
```

OR

```
$sql = $conn->query( "SELECT DISTINCT city FROM countries ORDER BY city WHERE city LIKE '(%' AND LIKE '_)%'" );
```